# decimal formatting with more elegance C++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
            void FeetInches::decimal() 
            {
                if (inches == 6.0)
                {
                    inches = 5;
                    std::cout << feet << "." << inches << " feet";  //not the best but works..
                }
            }
```

This will print something like 12 feet 6 inches as 12.5 feet.  I would prefer to not use this "hackish" method and make it like this:

```
            void FeetInches::decimal() 
            {
                if (inches == 6.0)
                {
                    inches = .5;
                    std::cout << feet << inches << " feet";  //not the best but works..
                }
            }
```

But this will print 60.5 inches (I need 6.5 inches).  Basically if I print inches alone it prints 0.5.  I want inches to print only .5 without the zero.  Cant a printf method or another quick technique implement this?  The data types are double by the way

Comment: You could convert your feet and inches to just feet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about converting your inches to feet first:

```
feet = feet + inches / 12.0;
```

Now print out the result. Or if you don't want to change your `feet` variable, either do the calculation directly in your `cout` statement or use a temporary variable for the calculation.

Comment: Well, that definitely does not reinvent the wheel.  Thanks for the help.